# How would measuring the number of photons on a finite number of pulses break coherence of a weak coherent laser source in COW QKD protocol

Tags: lasers, photonics

I' m trying to understand attacks on Quantum key distribution protocols. In the COW QKD protocol, pulses from Alice are passed through an asymmetric
coupler and a fraction 'T' of the photons are sent to generate key, and the remaining fraction '1 − T' is sent into an interferometer to monitor coherence of consecutive pulses. In one of the [references](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0609090) "Zero-Error Attacks and Detection Statistics in the Coherent One-Way Protocol for Quantum Cryptography"by Gisin et al. I came across the sentence:

> If any two non-empty pulses are coherent and all pulses are equidistant, any attempt of measuring the number of photons on a finite number of pulses breaks some coherence and contributes to errors.

which I'm unable to understand.

Comment: Better on the Physics stack?

Comment: I concur, Mike. This is definitely physics